# How to handle a in the views a model that belongs to another and given its ID the view should display different info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-routes

Right now I'm making a website and I need to implement this functionality a user type Client belongs to a Company, so when it logs in, the Client should see a view regarding that company, I'm not sure how to handle this because he should see the company route ID, right now for example if the user is an Admin type I created a Namespace for it but that's because every admin can see the same info, the Client type should only see the company where he belongs, I'm not sure what should I be using, right now my route for that is defined like this

```
resources :companies, param: :slug, only: :show do
  resources :clients
end
```

That works but for example if the Client belongs to the company amazon and he logs in, he's redirected to **companies/amazon/clients**,  and it displays the proper info but if he changes the route for another for example **companies/adaddasdas/clients**, it stills shows the page as well with the amazon info, that just happens if I'm trying to access the resources inside companies like :clients in this example, if I try to access the resource companies itself **companies/amazon** if i put something different it does not work

What I want to know is how do you guys handle that, when an user model belongs to another but given the Id(in my case slug) of the **other** model, the user should be able to see just the info of that Id and as well se other resources for that Model. Should I use that or a namespace, or custom layout, I'm not sure how to solve it and there's no documentation regarding that topic.

Comment: It's not a big deal. Just create a before action in your client controller that compares the client parent company (you grab the Id of the client from the params, then retrieve the Client record with a find method, and then climb to the parent) to the company that is passed in the url (you grab the slug from params, then try to find a company with that same slug with a find by methid, and then compare to what you have just found from the client id)

Comment: Actually when I have routes with more than one param I do this check too. On top of other checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments you can do a basic ownership check in your client controller:

```
class Client < ApplicationController

before_action :check_client_owner

private 

def check_client_owner
    unless params[:slug].to_s == Client.find(params[:id]).company.slug.to_s
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end

end
```

Also you can first make a check to know if the client exists. In case someone type a client ID that doesn't exist, it will trigger an error on the previous check (`Client.find(params[:id])` will not succeed).

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue, at the end I ended up giving up with slugs, I did it with just the id but can you tell me why I receive this params <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"client/clients", "action"=>"index", "company_id"=>"1"} permitted: false> I mean the company_id is a string so I needed to do params[:company_id].to_i Why I'm receiving that like a string?

Comment: I am not too sure about your question. But basically all params are strings. They are taken directly from the querystring / URL and appear as such. My `to_s` was probably redundant, just an habit. If you explicitly want an integer so yes `to_i` is useful, provided you are sure your id is a string with a number inside. if it is a pure string (that doesn't look like a number) you will get 0 : `"hello123".to_i` return  `0` in console.